# p5.js how to make example sketch run (what is the event bound to the run button)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I run the following example sketch I must first click the run button to make it work.
https://p5js.org/examples/sound-frequency-spectrum.html

When I copy the code and run it at localhost it does not include the run button event to start it. What event do I need to start the sketch ?

I feel like this information should mentioned in the sketch description so users can get up and running fast. I tried looking in developer tools and concluded it's easier to just ask.

```
let mic;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 200);

  // Create an Audio input
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();

  // start the Audio Input.
  // By default, it does not .connect() (to the computer speakers)
  mic.start();
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  // Get the overall volume (between 0 and 1.0)
  let vol = mic.getLevel();
  fill(127);
  stroke(0);

  // Draw an ellipse with height based on volume
  let h = map(vol, 0, 1, height, 0);
  ellipse(width / 2, h - 25, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to start the audioContext with a user gesture and in p5.js you set the following function to an eventListener:

```
userStartAudio()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is include the p5 dom library also, it will be automatically included when you downloaded the file from the p5.js website or you are using the p5js web editor, if not you might add this in your HTML code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can do this in your HTML code, you can add the button tag in the body tag.

```
<button id="button" onlick="runCode();"></button>
```

In javascript, you can do

```
function runCode() {
  loop();
}
```

And in setup, you must add

```
noLoop();
```

after every line in setup